# Proof that there exists $x= c$ s.t. $f(c)=c$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in  interval $x\in[a,b]$
>   s.t. $f(x) \in [a,b]$ . Then prove that there exists $c \in [a,b]$
>   s.t. $f(c)=c$ .

My Attempt

Let a function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ , Now all we need to do is prove that $g(c)=0$ .
I don't know how to take it from here

It is quite easy to visualize that whole function lies in rectangle and we have to travel left to right side s.t. graph doesn't break so it will cut diagonal atleast once . But I don't know how to put it mathematically .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$a\leq f(a)\quad \text{and}\quad f(b)\leq b$$ 
therefore if $a=f(a)$ or $b=f(b)$, we are done. Else
$$g(a)=f(a)-a>0 \text{ and } g(b)=f(b)-b<0$$
thus $g$ has a root $c$ such that $g(c)=0$, i.e. $f(c)=c$

Comment: So Correct me if I am wrong ,if f(x) is a continuous function in $[a,b]$ , s.t. $f(b)>f(a)$ then it attains each value from $[f(a),f(b)]$ atleast once in this intervel